# Could not load settings file at: 4.7.0 wordpress

Tags: import

I tried to load my contact to civicrm using the command line however was i tried to execute the import.php i received an error"could not load the settings file at:

i tried to further investigate i noticed that my civicrm.config.php is identical to the other server i used before that works perfectly fine as i tried the command line this error always comes up.

please do help a newbie.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to 4.7.4.  There was a bug in civicrm.config.php in 4.7.0 that would result ib the settings file not being found in WP under certain circumstances.